# Dar formato a una cadena en Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

Tengo una columna que se llama pos_aran cuyo formato es `99999999999X` y quiero convertirlo a `9999.99.99.999X`. Por ejemplo quiero que `12345678901A` se convierta en`1234.56.78.901A`. ¿Existe una función que cumpla con este proposito? Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT FUNC(pos_aran, '99.9999.999A') FROM foo
```

Antes de dar una respuesta, por favor consideren lo siguiente:

- No quiero usar `LEFT(pos_aran, 2)||'.'||SUBSTR(pos_aran, 3, 4)...` ya que no se ve bien para mi gusto y
  ocupa mucho espacio.
- Estoy haciendo las consultas desde Python, sin embargo, no sirve para mi objetivo la idea de dar formato a la cadena desde este lenguaje. Quiero hacerlo dentro de la consulta.

Comment: Qué versión de postgresql?

Comment: @Alfabravo Hice una consulta a la base de datos y me devolvió esto, espero que sirva: `PostgreSQL 10.13, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 64-bit`

Comment: Última pregunta: definitivamente los valores en la columna tienen letras? Es para descartar opciones

Comment: @Alfabravo perdona la tardanza, si, el ultimo caracter de pos_aran siempre será un numero o una letra.

Comment: Tienes razon, no querría que la base de datos fuera lenta. Si no cualquier cosa puedo optar por el primer punto que quiero evitar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar [regex_replace](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/regexp_replace/):

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(pos_aran,'(\d{4})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{3}[A-Z])', '\1.\2.\3.\4') FROM foo;
```

Si el último caracter puede ser un número (o no haber nada) puedes hacer con el último grupo variaciones:

```
(\d{3}[A-Z0-9]) 3 números y una letra o número
(\d{3}[A-Z0-9]?) 3 números y (opcionalmente) una letra o un número
```

Comment: En mi caso no tiene efecto, ¿en que parte debo poner la columna para que se aplique el formato?

Comment: Me he equivoqué con la entrada, le faltaban un par de 9. Funciona si hay 13 dígitos

Comment: Modifiqué ligeramente tu consulta, la probé y funcionó! Gracias! La consulta es `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(pos_aran,'(\d{4,4})(\d{2,2})(\d{2,2})(\d{3,3}[A-Z])', '\1.\2.\3.\4') FROM foo`.

Comment: se puede simplificar, voy a actualizar

Comment: Por desgracia, parece no funcionar si el ultimo caracter es un numero... Hay alguna solución a ello???

Comment: Por cierto, tu simplificación funciona, gracias!

Comment: Me parece que el formato de la columna no era tan exacto como pensaba, perdon

Comment: la solución es flexibilidar la regex

Comment: Tu idea funcionó gracias! Parece que los ultimos dos caracteres pueden estar ausentes.